# Nuxt generate dynamic pages based on .json file data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am having a fairly easy problem.

In my nuxt app I want to display a list of items based on objects in an array in a simple .json file. Furthermore when the specific item is clicked I want to show a detailed view of that item with more data. Imagine it is a list about cars, a dynamic route would look like: "cars/ford-500".

Now if I populate a vuex variable and display that in the dynamic route component - I dont get the SEO benefits since its loaded by the client. Furthermore if I want to refresh the page with the dynamic link I get an error because the store is deleted after refresh. Another option  is passing a route parameter but then again on refresh I get the error.

Basically I dont want to create 100 html pages I just want to let nuxt-generate do it automatically with my .json file and I want to display the specific data for that list item when I reload the dynamic route. I know nuxt-generate does not look at dynamic paths but there is a nuxt-generate property in the config file one can use to tell them to loop through.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

If you want Nuxt.js to generate routes with dynamic params, you need to set the generate.routes property to an array of dynamic routes.

If you have a list with the urls you can do it like so:

```
 // nuxt.config.js

 generate {
    routes () {
      // You can also import this from a js file.
      const yourUrls = ['ford-500', 'porche-spyder', 'mclaren-senna', 'volkswagen-beetle'];
      const routesToGenerate = [];

      for (const url of yourUrls) {
        const newRoute = '/cars/' + url;
        routesToGenerate.push(newRoute);
      }

      return routesToGenerate;
    }
}
```

Of course you can use a .json file as well

```
 // nuxt.config.js

 generate {
    routes () {
      const routesToGenerate = [];

      for (const urlKey of Object.keys(yourJsonFile)) {
        const newRoute = '/cars/' + yourJsonFile[urlKey];
        routesToGenerate.push(newRoute);
      }

      return routesToGenerate;
    }
}
```

If you need to you can also pass payload into the component you're generating. You can read more about it in the documentation here. (https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#routes)

#### Nuxt-i18n

If you are using an internationalization module like nuxt-i18n you'll need to manually define the locale prefix

```
 // nuxt.config.js

 generate {
    routes () {
      // You can also import this from a js file.
      const yourUrls = ['ford-500', 'porche-spyder', 'mclaren-senna', 'volkswagen-beetle'];
      const yourLocales = ['da-DK', 'en', 'de']
      const routesToGenerate = [];

      for (const url of yourUrls) {
        const defaultRoute = '/cars/' + url;
        routesToGenerate.push(defaultRoute);
            for (const locale of yourLocales) {
                const localeRoute = locale + '/cars/' + url;
                routesToGenerate.push(localeRoute);
            }
      }

      return routesToGenerate;
    }
}
```